# Snakemake add checkpoint output to DAG and report

Tags: snakemake

What I currently want to get going is, to add all the files created in "someDir/" to my DAG and add them to my report. The problem is mainly that those files are created in the checkpoint, thus I can't define them as wildcards beforehand. The allFiles(wildcards) currently returns me the directory and not the files.

```
checkpoint someRule:
    input:
        "output/some.rds"
    output:
        directory("someDir/")

def allFiles(wildcards):
    checkpoints.someRule.get(**wildcards).output[0] # is "output/some.rds" instead of wildcards
    filenames, = glob_wildcards("someDir/{filenames}")
    return expand("someDir/{fn}", fn=filenames)



rule all:
    input: 
         allFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. If someone has the same problem, this worked for me.

```
def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.someRule.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand('someDir/{i}',
           i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, '{i}')).i)
```

There still remains the problem, that the DAG doesn't include the checkpoint "someRule"